# MS server 2016 terminal gets freezes during user login with profiles disk

Tags: terminal-server, microsoft

We have Hypervisor and there are a few vms, one of them is MS server 2016 with last updates as terminal server. We use profiles disk for users. Lately we started to get enormous freezes at this terminal server during process of user's login.

Additionally process of login is about 5 minutes, before the problem it was about 20-30 seconds.

We have tried to restore server from backups that are two months+ age and still the issue remains.

As soon as user has logged in terminal server has no freezes at all.

Others servers that use the same lan do not have such troubles.

We have tried to use different lan adapters of Hypervisor and again no luck.

Normally terminal server has 80+ users' session, but now even first user after reboot logging in is so long.

config of VM:

65 GB RAM /
16 core of cpu /
10 Gb LAN

What would you recommend to solve this issue?